# Xcode Cocoa how to get GUI components

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, viewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

Sorry for this simple question, but I don't understand how to get the references to my components in the GUI that I built in Main.storyboard. This is how it looks like right now:

[image]

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let myWindowController = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "abcd")) as! MyMainWindow
    myWindowController.showWindow(self)
```

The View Controller on the top left is my "MyMainWindow" (NSWindowController) with the ID "abcd". Now, I would like to access the components like this checkbox in Tab1 in my code:

[image]

In Android i.e. you do something like findViewById(R.id.idOfTheComponent), but I've seen that in Xcode you can Ctrl-Drag the Component into a ViewController. I didn't work though, when I tried to drag the checkbox into my ViewController.swift class. Can someone help?

Comment: Please go through this once https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: Is `ViewController` the class of the view controller of tab 1? You can't connect a checkbox to the view controller of a different scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to search for this problem is how to create IBOutlets or please refer to the [Apple documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html)